# How can I create a single Dataframe out of my python code that generates a dictionary for each iteration of a for loop?

Tags: python

my for loop generates about 80 individual dictionaries:

> ```
>   {'X: 0.81, 'y': 1.1, 'z': 0.5469}
>   {'X: 0.8,  'y': 1.1, 'z': 0.5464}
>   {'X: 0.79, 'y': 1.1, 'z': 0.5461}
>   {'X: 0.78, 'y': 1.1, 'z': 0.546}
>
>   But I simply want to send each of those dictionary values as a row in a single data frame with 
>   the >dataframe header is equal to the key:
>   x          y              z
>   0.81       1.1            0.5469
>   0.8        1.1            0.5464
>   0.79       1.1            0.546
>   0.78       1.1            0.546
> ```

Comment: Store the dictionaries in a list, call `pd.DataFrame` on the list...

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of dictionaries

```py
rows = [
  {'X: 0.81, 'y': 1.1, 'z': 0.5469},
  {'X: 0.8,  'y': 1.1, 'z': 0.5464},
  {'X: 0.79, 'y': 1.1, 'z': 0.5461},
  {'X: 0.78, 'y': 1.1, 'z': 0.546}
]
```

and then create a DataFrame from them

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

If you care about performance, it is always better to create the list first and then create the DataFrame.  You could create the DataFrame first and add rows to it, but that will be slower because it creates a new DataFrame every time and copies everything over.

Comment: thanks, but each individual dictionary is being generated by a for loop, so when I use the pd.DataFrame procedure from Pandas then I seem to create only a collection of dataframes. So I need to use the pd.DataFrame inside the for loop and somehow generate a single dataframe

Comment: Create the empty list first outside of the loop, then append the dicts to the list inside the loop, then after the loop, create the DataFrame from the list.